# getElementById - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the Google autocomplete javascript code for address completion. It tracks the imput field getting the Id `document.getElementById('addressField')`. 
The problem I have is that the id of the input field looks like `myForm:j_idt329:addressField`.
I need this in many different pages. So the id looks each time different but always contains the word `addressField` at the end.
Is there another approach how to get the element? Maybe with RegEx? 
Here is the complete javascript:

```
function initialize() {

var input = document.getElementById('addressField');
var options = {
    types: ['geocode']
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex not needed! You can use `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector("[id*='addressField']")
```

If I remember correctly, the `*=` operator in a selector looks for elements that contain `addressField`

If you are trying to get a nodelist of multiple of these elements, simply use `querySelectorAll` instead. The former just returns the first node of the list, `all` returns the whole list.

As Lucas said in the comments: `$=` will match the end of the attribute. Both will work, not 100% sure if one is better than the other however.

Comment: Better yet, `$=` will match only if the attribute ends with the given string.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski there's that too yes! I wonder if there is a speed difference?

Comment: Sure, you'll get a microsecond improvement :)

Comment: That's a whole microsecond I didn't have before!