# Select partial ID name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net webform where I include the following script (on a separate .js file):

```
function pageLoad() {
    var mpe = $find("mpeEmpresa");
    mpe.add_shown(onShown);
    $addHandler(document, "keydown", onKeyDown);
}
function onShown() {
    var background = $find("mpeEmpresa")._backgroundElement;
    background.onclick = function() {
    $find("mpeEmpresa").hide();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it won't work because asp.net 3.5 changes the elements id's. The only way I could get it to work is to use `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_empresaFilha_mpeEmpresa` as the ID.

Sure I could use `<%= mpeEmpresa.ClientID %>` from the asp.net side, it would work but I'll have to pass that as a var to my external .js file and it's not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have searched on a few ways to select the element by it's ID name partially, but couldn't get any of them to work... Is there a guaranteed way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25207691/774078 one of my old answers may help here. `*=` in a selector means "contains"

Comment: add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the element to keep the original id.

Comment: $find('[id$="mpeEmpresa"]') end with selector can help you

Comment: btw, how @NawedKhan says, if you use selector in separate js file, css class selector should be the best approach

Comment: I was avoiding using the class selector solution because I don't find it very elegant. Unfortunately, neither that, nor `$find('[id$="mpeEmpresa"]')` is not working for me, for some strange reason.

Comment: $find('[id$="mpeEmpresa"]') returns null. This way works: `$('[id$="pnlEmpresa"]')`, but only for applying `hide`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the JQuery tag on your question, so you can easily use this:

```
$('div[id*="mpeEmpresa"]')
```

As i know the `ContentPlaceHolders` are rendered as `div`.

**Update:**

If you need to select `empresaFilha` too so you can't use the above selector.

because `$('div[id*="mpeEmpresa"]')` select both of `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_empresaFilha` and `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_empresaFilha_mpeEmpresa`.

so you need to use this:

Select only `mpeEmpresa`:

```
$('div[id*="mpeEmpresa"]').css("background-color","blue");
```

Select only `empresaFilha`:

```
$('div[id*="mpeEmpresa"]').parent('div[id*="empresaFilha"]').css("background-color","red");
```

Or something like this, maybe this code isn't so optimized because i don't see your ASP code or rendered HTML so have to provide a general solution.

Comment: Catching the `_` might be a touch more reliable... `$('div[id*="_mpeEmpresa"]')`

Comment: Actually, mpeEmpresa is a `ModalPopupExtender`. Your solution will apply only to the background of the modal, thus not hiding the modal's panel itself... Unless I also apply the hiding to ´pnlEmpresa´ (the panel to which the mpe applies). Not sure why.

Comment: You can easily find it by searching `mpeEmpresa` in your browser's source code,isn't it? but about the hiding, it isn't soulution's problem, probably your Modal is rendered like this: <div id="empresaFilha"><div id="mpeEmpresa"></div></div> and when you hide the inner element using JS, the outer container still remains.

Comment: Actually, I can't find it in the source code of the rendered modal window. Also, I can use `$('div[id*="mpeEmpresa"]')` (and/or `$('div[id*="pnlEmpresa"]')`) only in the line where I do the `hide()`. Attempting to use either of them on the vars (first line of each function) won't work.

Comment: Try this `$find($('div[id*="mpeEmpresa"]').attr('id'))` and let me know the result.

Comment: My project uses JQuery 1.7.1, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: JQuery 1.7.1 support this selectors but i'm not sure about `$find` `.add_shown` `._backgroundElement`. I think they must be something in Microsoft Ajax Library but i don't know what are those. The `.hide()` works fine because it's also in JQuery library. i think your question is answered and selectors works fine, the other problems maybe related to your Microsoft Ajax code. you can see updated answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this

```
var mpe=$('div[id$="mpeEmpresa"]');
```

or

```
 var mpe=$find('div[id$="mpeEmpresa"]');
```